# JABX xml written on a single line. How do i format

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

for those who tried the JAXB library, is there a way to create the file properly formatted?
The output is a 1 line file, and it gives me big problems. >,<

```
//xml creation
    JAXBContext ctx = null;
    try {
        ctx= JAXBContext.newInstance("Pojo");
        Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(train, new File(xml_output_file_path));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to enable pretty-print:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE );
```

Answer (score 0):

Before marshalling, add:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
```

To add `UTF-8` encoding, set property to marshaller:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: By default the output will be UTF-8 encoded.